# Create instance of generic class based on nullable type

Tags: c#

I want to create generic function which will take value of some type as parameter.

- This type could be nullable or not.
- If value is null function should returns null.
- If it's not null, and it's not nullable type than function should returns `MyGenericClass<T>(parameter)` (parameter could be also set by property there is no need to use constructor here)
- If it's not null, and it's nullable type than function should return something like `MyGenericClass<NotNullType(T)>(parameter.Value)` **example**: for parameter int? x, function should return `MyGenericClass<int>(x.Value)`.

Here is code which I've written to do such operation but without success:

```
private MyGenericClass GetMyGenericClassOrNull<T> (T value) {
    if (value != null) {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
        if (underlyingType == null) {
            return new MyGenericClass<T>(value);
        } else {
            return new MyGenericClass<underlyingType>(value);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can expect line: `return new MyGenericClass<underlyingType>(value);` is problematic here.

Is there any way to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with:

```
public class MyGenericClass
{
}

public class MyGenericClass<T> : MyGenericClass
{
    public MyGenericClass(T value)
    {
    }
}

public static MyGenericClass GetMyGenericClassOrNull<T>(T? value) where T : struct
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return new MyGenericClass<T>(value.Value);
    }

    return null;
}

public static MyGenericClass GetMyGenericClassOrNull<T>(T value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return new MyGenericClass<T>(value);
    }

    return null;
}
```

You have two separate methods. Nullable types will go to the first one, where `T` is the non-nullable "base" type.

Note that you can make the signatures `public static MyGenericClass<T>` without any problem if you want. It isn't clear how your `MyGenericClass` is built.

Comment: Getter method which returns void?)

Comment: @Toddams Corrected... I needed to make it compilable on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of the generic type by using [`Type.MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx).

There is a problem with your approach though: `MyGenericClass<int?>` (as example) is not `MyGenericClass<int>`. It is not possible to cast them. The type of `T` from the input is different from its output. I ignored that problem by supplying a secondary type parameter, which fixes the problem now.

```
private static MyGenericClass<T2> GetMyGenericClassOrNull<T, T2>(T value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
        if (underlyingType == null)
        {
            return new MyGenericClass<T2>((T2)(object)value);
        }
        else
        {
            Type t = typeof(MyGenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(underlyingType);

            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t, value);

            return (MyGenericClass<T2>)o;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var x = GetMyGenericClassOrNull<int?, int>(2);
```